# Unable to solve in NodeJS: 'TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON'

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have overtaken an internal software tool from a former employee at our company that is written in NodeJS and is connected to a salesforce shop system currently.

Unfortunately, I'm relatively new to NodeJS and my job currently is to connect the tool to a new shopware 6 (sw6) system and have all the functionality mapped to the new shop system which are for example creating job postings on the shop system.

I have checked and established a connection to the sw6 in an isolated manner but I'm failing to have a job posted on the sw6 system end-2-end, beginning from the Jobposting form in the internal software tool to having a landingpage in the shop system for the created job.

I may share you the code of the function that I'm trying to adjust:

```
exports.postNewJob = function(req, res) {
    var jobOffer = {
        active              : true,
        UserId              : req.user.id,
        jobId               : req.body.jobName + "-" + req.body.marketId + "-" + req.body.jobType,
        jobTitle            : jobMapper.mapJobId(req.body.jobName) + jobMapper.mapJobType(req.body.jobType),
        storeId             : req.body.marketId,
        storeLocation       : req.body.marketName,
        jobType             : req.body.jobType,
        hoursWeek           : req.body.workingHours_Week? req.body.workingHours_Week : null,
        hoursMonth          : req.body.workingHours_Month? req.body.workingHours_Month : null,
        christmasBonus      : req.body.christmasBonus? true : false,
        holidayPay          : req.body.holidayPay? true : false,
        employeeDiscount    : req.body.employeeDiscount? true: false,
        freeDrinks          : req.body.freeDrinks? true : false,
        bav                 : req.body.bav? true : false,
        vwl                 : req.body.vwl? true : false,
        vacationAmount      : req.body.vacation,
        otherBenefits       : req.body.otherBenefits,
        contactMail         : req.body.contactEmail,
        contactPartner      : req.body.contactName,
        contactMarket       : req.body.contactPlace,
        contactStreet       : req.body.contactStreet + "&nbsp;",
        contactStreetNumber : req.body.contactStreetNumber,
        contactZipCode      : req.body.contactPLZ + "&nbsp;",
        contactCity         : req.body.contactCity,
        countryCode         : req.body.site,
        author              : req.user.emailAdress,
        hrLink              : req.body.hrLink,
        promoted            : false,
        promotionValue      : "",
        promotionBillingAdress : req.body.premiumBillingAdress
    };
    var premium = req.body.premium;
    var premiumLimit = req.body.premiumLimit;
    var premiumBillingAdress = req.body.premiumBillingAdress;
    var jobName = req.body.jobName;

           models.JobType.findAll()
            .then(function(jobTypes) {
                models.JobPostingsMarket.findOrCreate({ where: {jobId: jobOffer.jobId}, defaults: jobOffer})
                    .then(function(jobPosting){
                        console.log("Saved new job posting with following job id: " + jobOffer.jobId);
    
                        shopwareAuth.getToken(config.CLIENT_ID_SW, config.CLIENT_PASSWORD_SW, config.SHOPWARE_INSTANCE, req.user.emailAdress, req.session, function(err, accessToken){
                            if(err) {
                                console.error("ERROR: Could not authenticate with shopware. Error: " + err);
                                res.render('app/market/jobs/form', {createError : true, jobOffer, jobName : jobName, premium : premium, premiumLimit : premiumLimit, premiumBillingAdress : premiumBillingAdress, user : req.user, jobTypes : jobTypes});
                            } else {
                                var requestBody = {
                                    'id': md5(jobOffer.jobId),
                                    'name': jobOffer.storeId + " - " + jobOffer.jobTitle,
                                    'url': jobOffer.jobId,
                                    'active': true,
                                    'salesChannels':[{'id':'XXX'}],
                                    'cmsPageId': 'XXX'
                                };
                                var headers = {
                                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                };    
                                const options = {
                                    url: config.SHOPWARE_INSTANCE + '/api/landing-page/',
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    headers: headers,
                                    data: requestBody                 
                                };
    
                                console.log(options);
                                
                                axios.request(options)
                                    .then(response => {
                                        console.log("Created new Job Landing Page with ID: " + jobOffer.jobId)
                                        console.log(response.data);
                                    }) 
                                    .catch(err => {
                                        console.error('ERROR: An error occurred while sending data to shopware: ');
                                        console.error(err);
                                        res.render('app/market/jobs/form', {createError : true, jobOffer, jobName, premium, premiumLimit, premiumBillingAdress, user : req.user, jobTypes : jobTypes});
                                    })
                                    .then(() => {
            
                                        console.log({createJob : true, user : req.user, jobTypes : jobTypes});
                                        res.render('app/market/jobs/form', {createJob : true, user : req.user, jobTypes : jobTypes});         
                                    })
                                    .catch(err => {
                                        console.error(err.response.data);
                                        res.render('app/market/jobs/form', {createError : true, jobOffer, jobName, premium, premiumLimit, premiumBillingAdress, user : req.user, jobTypes : jobTypes});
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    .catch(err=>{
                        console.error("ERROR: An error occurred while saving the new job posting to MariaDB: " + err);
                        res.render('app/market/jobs/form', {createError : true, jobOffer, jobName, premium, premiumLimit, premiumBillingAdress, user : req.user, jobTypes : jobTypes});                        
                    });
                })    
                .catch(err=>{
                    console.error("ERROR: An error occurred while loading job types on new job page.")
                    console.error(err);
                    res.redirect('/error');
                });
    }
```

When I'm trying to create a Job, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at hash (C:\Users\Klat\TOOL\TOOL\node_modules\express-session\index.js:594:18)
    at isSaved (C:\Users\Klat\TOOL\TOOL\node_modules\express-session\index.js:427:54)
    at shouldSave (C:\Users\Klat\TOOL\TOOL\node_modules\express-session\index.js:445:12)
    at ServerResponse.end (C:\Users\Klat\TOOL\TOOL\node_modules\express-session\index.js:330:11)
    at Gzip.onStreamEnd (C:\Users\Klat\TOOL\TOOL\node_modules\compression\index.js:212:14)
    at Gzip.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

I have tried a lot of stuff in order to debug this error but I have a hard time understanding what the problem is and at which point exactly the error gets raised.

I hope that the information delivered is sufficient for you to understand my problem.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Might there be some logic in your express server which attaches _httpMessage to another object that is itself referred to within _httpMessage? Admittedly I have not tracked through your code in detail, but at first sight there does not seem to be anything that would give rise to the error. What else has been written to the console log prior to the error being reported? It could be worth adding more logging to narrow down the point at which the error arises.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing really logged prior to the error message.
But I suppose the line that probably leads to the error is this one:
`res.render('app/market/jobs/form', {createJob : true, user : req.user, jobTypes : jobTypes});`          
If I leave out json in the function parameters, the error doesn't appear but then, of course, another error occurs in the View for the 'app/market/jobs/form' route because of missing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, I was able to find the problem just right now with some inspiration from this Post here: [TypeError: circular structure to JSON starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest' property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'Socket'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459084/typeerror-circular-structure-to-json-starting-at-object-with-constructor-clien)

In the function for requesting the sw6 access token (`shopwareAuth.getToken`), which I had already adapted from the old salesforce token request function, I made use of the complete response from the OAuth2 query response which was wrong as only the res.data part was needed.